# Which relationship is more natural?

Tags: java, design, object-oriented, architecture

Have a quick question on how to best structure something for my Java project:

I'm a user. I can work at one or more places. At those workplaces, I have one or more roles. For each of these roles, I work a shift.

I either came up with:

My workplaces have shifts, my shifts have exactly 1 position (what position did I work when I worked my shift? It varies day to day..)

or

Workplaces have positions, each position has shifts

I think the 2nd is more natural but keep going back and forth / unsure of what has more of an advantage both now and for the future. It's hard for me as I can argue both I guess?

Thanks!

Comment: How about creating a session class that keeps the mapping between user, workplace,role and shift for one occurrence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might make the most sense to look at how you'll use those structures in your code. If you're writing a scheduling app, then putting shifts higher might make more sense because they're a scheduling artifact. If you're doing a HR app, then putting positions higher might make sense because you're worried about managing people and their roles.

An entity-relationship diagram would help, although you've pretty much got it laid out already.

But it's actually both. A workplace "has a" list of positions, but also "has a" list of shifts. Shifts will have additional information, like start and end time. And a shift "has a" position that describes what to do during that shift.

Another way to think of it is, a shift "realizes" a position. That is, it makes it real by adding scheduling information.

Here's another alternative: Positions and shifts are top-level entities, and they "have a" reference to a workplace.

You might bust out a simple Entity-Relationship diagram, and then decide which of the relationships (and in what direction) you want to model in your code. Some of the relationships you can rely on queries and joins to pull from your database.

Comment: Thanks for such a great response. Ultimately, the purpose of this is to total up the # of sales you've made by workplace and position. So the homepage (dashboard) shows the picture of a week (your current week) laid out for you and shows you the amount of money you've made each day. You have drop down lists on the top to change the position (for a workplace) or even change the workplace itself. What do you suggest? By the way I don't actually have a property on workplace called shifts, I only have it called positions. But shift has a property called WorkplaceID, and has one called PositionID

Comment: oh one other thing - I rarely need to get all the sales at once, rather just by week. Does that affect anything in terms of how it's loaded? I guess initialization is another question alltogether.

Comment: I started to type an answer, but then, what the hell do I know? :) Modelling is so, so subjective. You should try it out and see what you like.